# "default" access_token used by PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When there is no active user session Facebook PHP SDK uses `appid|appsecret` string as `access_token`

Is this exact special kind of token described somewhere in documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A token that contains appId|appSecret is the [Application Access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#app-login).

Comment: Look at the screenshot at the link you gave - application token contains of `appid|random_fb_string`. And there is nothing about `appid|appsecret` at all. Not an answer.

Comment: There's two ways to generate an Application Access Token, one way is to use 'appId|appSecret' , the other way is as in the doc I linked to. I was only linking to demonstrate the purpose of the token.

Comment: the question is: "Is this exact special kind of token described somewhere in documentation?". I didn't ask about the purpose. I'm just curious about if it is described somewhere in doc or we need to examine php sdk sources to get information about it.

Comment: It's not described anywhere since it's no different to an App Access token, it's simply a more convenient way to generate it.

Comment: it is not different but it is useful for building custom tools. It should be documented. Don't you think so? As long as they are similar - why does documentation describe more difficult case?

Comment: I suppose there's no reason to *not* document it, true. I'll chat to the docs team tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, so just to circle back on this. The reason we don't document it is that it's not a very secure way to do it and we'll probably shut it down at some point. It does still work, but we aren't going to officially support it, so I wouldn't put it in anything mission critical. I'm making an amendment to the PHP SDK to have us generate the App Token the correct, documented way.

Comment: ok, this soulution is acceptable too. Btw, don't see any security issues with it - as soon as you already know both id + secret - you can get application token.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is specifically about the PHP SDK, but is there an equivalent for the JS SDK? I wondering how I could seamlessly integrate the fallback to Application Token when there is no logged in Facebook user with the JS SDK.

Comment: That would be insecure, as long as there is no private key used on client side. I doubt it exists.